# Asynchronous ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, ngoninit

Is it allowed to have ngOnInit() return a promise?

I see a lot of code written that way that seems to be working.

However, a non-observed promise can be resolved/rejected at any time, for instance when component is not allowed to be modified.

Also, the type signature of ngOnInit is just

> () => void

, not the

> () => void|Promise

.

Answer (score 0):

No. As you observed, ngOnInit is a void method - it doesn't return anything